# how to pass data to view and get it

Tags: php, codeigniter

My framework is `codeigniter` .

I'm using `mPDF` library. (a library to create pdf file).
now, I would like to make a pdf file.

`mpdf` lib has a function like this :

```
$pdf->WriteHTML($html);
```

I want to pass my `data` to a `view` file and get result of it but I don't want to show any `view` to user .

```
$html = $this->load->view('print' ,$data,true);
```

above code load `print` view to user .

my code is over 200 line :

> http://codepad.org/qDDHfn57

how to solve this problem ?

Comment: If you want only `contents` from view then you can pass one `flag` with `$data` and in view use `flag` in condition, may be that can help you.

Comment: Open pdf directly without opening any view file.Is this you want ?

Comment: @Bugfixer, no, creating pdf file directly without opening any view file.

Comment: I dont about mpdf but Have you tried [ezpdf](http://www.ahowto.net/php/easily-integrate-ezpdf-a-k-a-pdf-php-into-codeigniter-framework/) library.It is simple for generating pdf out of query results.

Comment: I have a custom html file. at the first time, I must pass data to view and when view is completed, from the result of it I must create pdf .

Comment: That means you are performing operation in view.

Comment: post a snippet of your controller, your view file isn't relevant here

Answer (score 1):

```
$html = $this->load->view('print' ,$data,true);
$pdf->WriteHTML($html);
```

**after using this you can redirect to other page.**

or load other view show a pdf file or else

Answer (score 0):

Put mpdf60 folder in Library.

In controller put following code.

```
public function doprint($book_id,$pdf=false)
{
    $this->load->library('parser'); 
    $page_data['sold_book'] = "Hello world data";    
    $output = $this->parser->parse('sold_book_detail_print',$page_data,true);   
    if ($pdf=='print')
       $this->_gen_pdf($output); 
    else
        $this->output->set_output($output);             
}
//GENRATE PDF FILE
public function _gen_pdf($html,$paper='A4')
{
    //this the the PDF filename that user will get to download
    $pdfFilePath = "output_pdf_name.pdf";
    //load mPDF library
    $this->load->library('mpdf60/mpdf');
    $mpdf=new mPDF('utf-8',$paper);

    //generate the PDF from the given html
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
    $mpdf->Output();
}
```

Put following code in view.

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/soldtextbook/doprint/<?php echo $row->buy_book_id; ?>/print" target="_blank" class="post-ad">print shipping Detail</a>
```

And create file.php in view.and write html in file.php Ex:

```
<?php if(!empty($sold_book)){
    foreach($sold_book as $row){ ?>

<?php if($row->diffrent_address == "0"){ ?>
<div class="col-lg-7 col-md-8">
    <div class="book-detail-right">
        <div class="book-seller"><h4 style="color:#00a0db;">Shipping Address</h4></div>
        <div class="book-seller col-lg-12"><span class="col-lg-4" style="font-weight:bold;">Name:</span> <span class="col-lg-9"><?php echo $row->first_name. " " .$row->last_name; ?></span></div>
        <div class="book-seller col-lg-12"><span class="col-lg-4" style="font-weight:bold;">Address : </span><span><?php echo $row->address_1;?></span></div>
        <div style="margin-left:72px;"><span class="col-lg-9"><?php echo $row->address_2. "<br/>" .$row->city. "," .$row->county_name. ",<br/>United Kingdom- " .$row->postcode. ".";?></span></div>
        <div class="book-seller col-lg-12"><span class="col-lg-4" style="font-weight:bold;">phone : </span><span class="col-lg-9"><?php echo $row->phone_number;?></span></div>
    </div><!--en dof book-detail-right-->
</div><!--end of col-lg-8-->
<?php } ?>
```